# C#: Is the whole config sections approach now obsolete?

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

On MSDN site, the latest version page I can find which discusses [configuration sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is marked Visual Studio 2010, and if you try to find the Recommend Version it says "This Topic Is No Longer Available".

Is the configuration xml schema obsolete?  (and maybe replaced with something better?

I've done a lot of searching, and all the documentation on MSDN looks old, and even on SO, the most questions regarding custom configuration are at least 3 or more years old.

Can someone please point me to current documentation for using configuration files with C#?

Comment: Looks rather like they messed up linking or didn't finish this part - the parent level is still available for the current .NET Framework but all sub-elements, like your link, leave you stranded with VS 2010. But it's not like this functionality will rust - it still works fine and may still be there some time until json might take over.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration XML schema is still in use in .NET Framework (though possibly not in .NET Core), and hasn't really changed much in several versions so you should be okay looking at VS 2010 documentation.

Comment: I suppose I was hoping that it had been replaced by something better, since I find it way too complicated for what it does.